# Smart Contract Event Parsing With Web3swift and interacting with it swift

Tags: swift, event-handling, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3swift

I am using the web3swift library and I managed to read methods of the smart contract. But Not able to parse non-indexed events of the smart contract. can anyone give an example to parse non-indexed events of the smart contract?

Comment: can you open an issue on https://github.com/matter-labs/web3swift ? we will get you to update there